# Converting values inside nested stl containers

Tags: c++, casting, stl

My whole point is that I have a

```
struct S {
  double x, y;
  // some code defining properties and operations on such pairs.
  // ...
  // ... 
  operator std::pair<double, double>(){
    return {x,y};
  }
};
```

For semantic reasons, and to be able to define all those properties and operations inside `S`, I opted against using `std::pair<double, double>` and several global functions. Now this causes me a headache: for some reason, I need to convert a

```
std::vector<std::array<std::vector<S>, 3>>
```

to a

```
std::vector<std::array<std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>, 3>>
```

I know I can convert a `vector<T> v` to a `vector<U>` by saying `vector<U>(v.begin(), v.end()`. However, in such a nested situation, I have the impression that this gets unwieldy.

Are there any alternatives? Or should I rethink the whole approach?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Nexted in the sense that I have S inside vector inside array inside vector. I don't now to apply the general case here that you mentioned.

Comment: btw free functions are generally preferred over placing as much as you can inside a class. To have things where they belong you would use a namespace

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, but refactoring this for the existing code now is definitely not the preferred way. I will keep that in mind in future, though.

Comment: the fact that the elements are inside a vector is somewhat secondary. First you need to decide how you want to get a `std::array<std::pair<double, double>, 3>` from a `std::array<std::vector<S>, 3>`. The best solution is to not do this conversion in the first place. In generic code there would be no need to do so, you would use iterators and your `S` would have a `first` and `second` member

Comment: "Or should I rethink the whole approach?" imho yes. "but refactoring this for the existing code now is definitely not the preferred way" refactoring is always easier now than later

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Please see the updated question (change in the last code block, where a `vector` was missing.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're asking about, but more of a comment on your design: I would recommend against using such implicit conversion operators, and instead be explicit and use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a conversion lambda. Implicit conversion operators tend to come back and be used at the least expected and most bad situations.